# Most efficient way to list server status results

Tags: php, server, ping, status, heartbeat

I'm trying to determine the best way to show server status results.
We have roughly two dozen websites and services to maintain, and the old system they had here was crude (HTML, manual color change to reflect status), and I'm trying to re-vamp it a little.

What would be the best method for doing a simple heartbeat ping to an internal service, while cleanly listing them.

Also, has to be compatible with Sharepoint.

I've read that PHP is the baseline for this, but I can't find much in the way of a continuous ping/health monitor.

Answer (score 1):

This would need to be done client side, with an AJAX query to a script that runs the ping/heartbeat check code. With a callback that updates the status, based upon the ID.
Using `setInterval ()` will enable you to execute this on a regular basis, without requiring manual input.

Note that if you need to create such a system that can be opened from many clients, you might want to look into caching the heartbeat check result on the server side. To prevent self-flooding of the servers.

Comment: Yep, create some cron job which will get server statuses and store them somewhere on your server (file, database...). Then use that ajax call to get them from your server directly.